# How to set min Value a step down of min value received from database in Y Axis in ChartJS

Tags: laravel, chart.js

I am displaying a chart showing month on x and amount y from values received from database. Say
X = Jan21, Feb21, March21 and So on.
Y = 1000, 1500, 2000 and So on.
Step automatically coming 500.
Now when i plot the chart, starting value start with 1000 and chart showing from bottom which looks odd visually.
so can i get Y axis starting value as 500( step  value )
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

add this into your chart options

```
scales: {
        y: {
            min: 500,
            ticks: {
                stepSize: 500
            }
        }
    }
```